# error with navigate for undefined router in angular2

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular2-routing

I trying to add a click event to highcharts bar to navigate to another html view and loading another component. My current error from console is:

`Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined`

this is what i have in my component file:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';  

constructor(private myService: MyService, private router: Router) {}

plotOptions: {
                      bar: {
                          dataLabels: {
                              enabled: false
                          }
                      },
                      series: {
                          pointWidth: 15,
                          cursor: 'pointer',
                          point: {
                              events: {
                                  click: function(){
                                    this.router.navigate(['/nestedFolder/newPage.component.html']);
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

I am not sure that i fully understand why i am getting this error or if i am using the navigate the wrong way.

Folder Structure:

- main folder

  - main.component.ts
  - main.component.html
  - nestedFolder

    - newPage.component.html
    - newPage.component.ts

Comment: Have you created the router instance in the constructor ?

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht yes i created it (i updated my post to show it as well)

Comment: 'This' inside callback does not refer to the component - you have to bind 'this' dynamicaly - click: function () { ... }.bind(this)

Comment: @morganfree that did get rid of the error but now i am getting `Error: Cannot match any routes. ` I added the folder structure of my work in the bottom of my post. I would like to navigate to newPage.component from main.component.ts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not getting the proper value of `this` in your click function.

To solve this, you can create a `self` variable and assign `this` in the outer scope, and use `self.router.navigate` in your function.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';  

//Within your component
self;

constructor(private myService: MyService, private router: Router) {
  self = this; // Assign outer context to self
}

plotOptions: {
                      bar: {
                          dataLabels: {
                              enabled: false
                          }
                      },
                      series: {
                          pointWidth: 15,
                          cursor: 'pointer',
                          point: {
                              events: {
                                  click: function(){
//Change this to self  

self.router.navigate(['/nestedFolder/newPage.component.html']);
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

Comment: When i tried doing this and after writing: `self = this;` i am getting an error stating that `this` is not assignable to type `window` and my component is not assignable to type `window` and that property `applicationCache` is missing in my component. Also just fyi i am able to use `this` in other parts of my component just an issue is coming up when using router.